# Laravel route is redirecting too many times

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.4 for a project and scenario is if `user` does not have any `clubs` created then on login redirect `user` to `clubs/create` page.

Below is my route page coding

directory structure is `routes/backend/access.php`

```
Route::group([
    'prefix'     => 'access',
    'as'         => 'access.',
    'namespace'  => 'Access',
], function () {

Route::group([
    'middleware' => ['access.routeNeedsRole:3', 'first.run']
], function () {

   /*
    * Clubs Management
    */
    Route::group(['namespace' => 'Clubs'], function () {

    Route::get('create', 'ClubsController@showCreateOrganiser')->name('clubs.showCreateOrganiser');
        /*
         * Specific Club
         */
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'clubs/{club}'], function () {

            // Access
            Route::get('login-as', 'ClubsController@loginAs')->name('clubs.login-as');

        });

        //For when admin is logged in as user from backend
        Route::get('logout-as', 'ClubsController@logoutAs')->name('clubs.logout-as');


        /*Clubs CRUD*/
        Route::resource('clubs', 'ClubsController');


        //For DataTables
        Route::post('clubs/get', 'ClubsTableController')->name('clubs.get');

        });

    });
});
```

Below is my `FirstRunMiddleware.php` code

```
Class FirstRunMiddleware
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Clubs::scope()->count() === 0) {
            return redirect()->route('admin.access.clubs.showCreateOrganiser');

        }

        $response = $next($request);

        return $response;
    }
}
```

It redirects too many times and i get the error message that `redirected you too many times`.

What is it i am doing wrong here??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its because when its redirected to create page, the Middleware will work again! and it will check for clubs and redirect you to the same page again, and so on.

you need to make the create rout out of `FirstRunMiddleware` scope.

Comment: Git it. Needed to add a if condition. Thank you.